# Exception by counting attributes in a XML document with comments c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I want to count attributes in a XML document.
Without

it works well.
But with a comment I got an exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

It is possible to count in other way?
Or why the count methode don't ignore the comment line in the xml example?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"
           <ListOfMegaCities>
               <MegaCities city=""Moscow"" residents=""11503501"" foundation=""1624""/>
               <MegaCities residents=""8336817""/> <!-- comment test -->
               <MegaCities foundation=""1066""  city=""London""/>
           </ListOfMegaCities>");

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ListOfMegaCities");
Console.Write("\nCount Attributes: " + elemList[0].ChildNodes[0].Attributes.Count);
Console.Write("\nCount Attributes: " + elemList[0].ChildNodes[1].Attributes.Count);
Console.Write("\nCount Attributes: " + elemList[0].ChildNodes[2].Attributes.Count);
```

Comment: You can use the debugger to inspect which of the objects is null. I bet it is `elemList[0].ChildNodes[2].Attributes`. Also comments are nodes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

One single statement gives the answer without any loops.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<ListOfMegaCities>
               <MegaCities city='Moscow' residents='11503501' foundation='1624'/>
               <MegaCities residents='8336817'/> <!-- comment test -->
               <MegaCities foundation='1066'  city='London'/>
           </ListOfMegaCities>");
    
    int AttributeCounter = xdoc.Descendants("MegaCities")
        .Attributes().Count();
        
    Console.WriteLine("Total attributes counter: {0}", AttributeCounter);
}
```

**Output**

```
Total attributes counter: 6
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I read about the advantages with XML LINQ. Now I rewrite my code and try to use LINQ. But it is very hard for me... I try my best to learn the right way. ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"
           <ListOfMegaCities>
               <MegaCities city=""Moscow"" residents=""11503501"" foundation=""1624""/>
               <MegaCities residents=""8336817""/> <!-- comment test -->
               <MegaCities foundation=""1066""  city=""London""/>
           </ListOfMegaCities>");

            XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ListOfMegaCities");
            foreach(XmlNode childNode in elemList[0].ChildNodes)
            {
                if(childNode.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
                    Console.Write("\nCount Attributes: " + childNode.Attributes.Count);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I understand comments are also nodes.
More exception detailes:

[image]

I will try the solution above.